# UITabBarButton not taking accessibilityIdentifier

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, appium, uitabbaritem

I am setting the `accessibilityIdentifier` for our `tabBarItem` from programmatically. I am creating tabBar programmatically and only set the image of tabBarItem.

In iOS 9.x this worked fine and we could reference the correct tab bar button. In iOS 10 the `accessibilityIdentifier` is no longer set correctly at runtime

Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a known solution?